# EntityManger keeps id of removed object and doesn't refresh id after adding new one

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I have problem with removing objects using EnitityManager. I have parameter like name. When I add this param for user and then remove it- it works fine. But EntityManager remember id of removed parameter (Id is primary key - autoincrement). And when I add one more time this parameter for user  - EntityManager adds row to Database but it keeps id of the first persit(). So if I remove parameter value one more time - EM doesn't remove parameter - it remember id of the first parameter, so there is no parameter with this id.

My source code is:

```
   if (!param.isParameterFilled()) {
        if (param.getId() != null) {
            param = getEmGap().merge(param);
            getEm().remove(param);
            getEm().flush();
        }
        return;
    }
    if (param.getId() == null) {
        getEm().persist(param);
    } else {
        getEm().merge(param);
    }
    getEm().flush();
}
```

And maybe the problem is connected with condition: if(param.getId() == null) - in this case (after first adding and removing) id != null - > but in DB there is no param with id that EM knows. And I have no idea how to solve this problem. And I don't know how EM should works in this case? Should EM set Id = null after remove() and flush() are called. Or maybe persist() and flush() should reload Id of the parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend reincarnating objects.  If you want to persist a new object, then create a new object and persist it, do not use a formerly deleted instance.  When you remove an instance, there should be no references to it anymore, including from your app, as the object no longer exists.

Also, removing and persisting objects with the same id in the same transaction, is normally not a good idea.  If you can, try to use a unique id for each new object.

To confirm your error, you remove the same object with the same id twice it the same transaction and persist it once, and the second remove does not work?  What does not work, do you get an error, or is no SQL DELETE statement generated?  What JPA provider and version are you using?  Can you try separate transactions, instead of the same transaction.

Comment: Creating new object fixed the problem. The problem was not related to trasacions but using the same object. Thanks for your help.